# How to find repetitions/duplicates in the array within 10 elements apart

Tags: c#

I have an array like following:
`{1,5,5,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,1,16,17,5}`
I want to find duplicates within each 10 elements from one to another.

I need a code that can tell me that `5` was duplicated 3 times within 10 elements (there are at most only 1 element between 5s (4). It should igore last 5 as it is too far away. Only three 5s are within 10 elements).
I don't want code to return `1`, because there are 13 element in between both 1s.

I have a code that can count duplicates but how to change it so it can count duplicates withing 10 elements?

```
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach (var count in combined2)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(count))
                    dict[count]++;
                else
                    dict[count] = 1;
            }
            foreach (var val in dict)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(val.Key + " occurred " + val.Value + " times");
            }
```

I'm only concerned with duplicates that occur the most. If some number get duplicated twice but another gets duplicated 3 times. I would only like to know about number that got duplicated 3 times (withing 10 items). Thank you

Comment: You can limit the length inside for loop? count until 10 only

Comment: @Justcode: This would not catch anything in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code finds the first item with the higher number of occurrences inside the "numbers" array (within n = 10 elements):

```
int n = 10;
int[] numbers = new int[] {1,5,5,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,1,16,17,5};
int mostDuplicatedNumber = 0, numberOfMaxOccurrences = 0;

for(int count = 0; count < numbers.Length - n; count++)
{
    var groupOfNumbers = numbers.Skip(count).Take(n).GroupBy(i => i).OrderByDescending(i => i.Count());

    if(numberOfMaxOccurrences < groupOfNumbers.First().Count())
    {
        numberOfMaxOccurrences = groupOfNumbers.First().Count();
        mostDuplicatedNumber = groupOfNumbers.First().Key;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Most duplicated number is " + mostDuplicatedNumber + " with " + numberOfMaxOccurrences + " occurrences");
```

Answer (score 6):

- Make a dictionary `max` defaulting to `0`
- Make a dictionary `seen` defaulting to `0`
- Count `count` from `0` up to `N`, where `N` is number of elements.
- after `N >= 10`, decrement `seen[array[count - 10]]`
- Increment `seen[array[count]]`
- If that number is higher than `max[array[count]]`, update it
- Repeat
- Return the key of the highest value in `max`.

This way, `seen` always has the accurate count in the 10-element window, and `max` will have the maximum number of appearances of each element in a 10-element window.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this way. I have not tested using IDE just wrote while travelling. Let me know if you encounter any error. What it does simply take first 10 elements and finds number of occurrence i.e. repetition but then ( you would like to display most repeated number in that case you have to hold those repeated numbers in another array and swap the elements to get most repeated and least repeated one as you asking in your question I have not implemented this part ) .

```
         .................


     int[] inputArray= {1,5,5,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,1,16,17,5} // total input elements
         int[] mostAndLeastOccuranceArray=new int[10] ;


                   int skip=0;
                   int limit=10;
                   int[] resultArray=new int[10];
                    for (int i = skip; i < inputArray.Length; i++)   
                    {  
                        if(i<limit)
                       {
                       resultArray[i]=inputArray[i];
                       skip=skip+1;
                       }else
                        {
                          findOccurance(resultArray); // call in every 10 elements array subset
                    resultArray=new int[10]; // re-initialize the array 
                    limit=limit+10; // increase the limit for next iteration remember loop has not finished yet

                        } 

                    } 



    public void findOccurance(int[] resultArray)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary < int,int > ();  
             foreach(var value in resultArray)  
             {  
                        if (dict.ContainsKey(value)) dict[value]++;  
                        else dict[value] = 1;  
              }

              foreach(var pair in dict)
              {
                       mostAndLeastOccuranceArray[pair.Key]=pair.Value; // store the repeated value
                       Console.WriteLine("Value {0} occurred {1} times", pair.Key, pair.Value);  

               }  
// call the method to find most and least occurance elements within each array subsets
findMostAndLeastOccuranceElements(mostAndLeastOccuranceArray)
// re-initialize 
 mostAndLeastOccuranceArray=new int[10] ;


    }

    public void findMostAndLeastOccuranceElements(int[] mostAndLeastOccuranceArray)
    {
     // now find most and least repeated elements within each 10 elements block

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to use LINQ. Here I wrote a simple method to count the number of time a value is repeated.

```
public int CountRepetitions(List<int> myLists,int maxValues,int number)
{
    if (myLists.Count > maxValues)
        return myLists.Take(maxValues).Count(v => v == number);
    else return 0;
}
```